# How to pass a value between 2 components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 separate components, Form component is the step 1 where you enter your name, then by clicking `<Link />` you go to the next step which is Welcome component.

How can I pass the name value {this.state.value} from Form component to Welcome component so it can retrieve what was typed in the Form component.

Form component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'react-router';

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ''      
    };      
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='root'>
        <p>Setup the engine analysation presentation to demo incubation functionality.</p>
        <div className='fieldRow'>
          Name
          <input type="text" autoFocus value={this.state.value} placeholder='Enter Name...'  />
        </div>
        <div className='btnWrapper'>
          <Link to='/welcome' >Access Demo</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Form
```

Welcome component:

```
import React from 'react';

class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='root'>
        Welcome <!-- Name Input from Form component -->
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Welcome;
```

Comment: A common technique for when you want to share state between two "sibling" components, is to [lift the state up to the first common ancestor](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Alternatively you could use a state management library like Redux or MobX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass it as state like this

```
<Link to={{
 pathname: '/welcome',
 state: {
  name: this.state.value
 }
}}>Access Demo</Link>
```

Then get it on welcome page (component) using `withRouter`

```
const { location } = this.props;
const name = location && location.state && location.state.name;
```

Comment: That is the simplest solution! Thanks for that.

Comment: Quick question: What if you want to pass it to a component that is not the next component, hence no <Link /> to pass the state.

Comment: 1) you can have a parent component that is gonna store all your states, you can pass it to its children. 2) use context api to have main store 3) redux